# What exactly does this news story mean by "magnetic charge"?

Tags: magnetic-monopoles, popular-science

I recently saw [this article](http://www.livescience.com//28149-antimatter-magnetic-charge-measured.html) in my Google News page, whose headline and first paragraph are:

> **Antimatter's Magnetic Charge Revealed**
>
> Scientists say they've made the most precise measurements to date of the magnetic charge of single particles of matter and its spooky counterpart antimatter.

From my intro-level E&M class, and [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), I was under the impression that, by definition, a magnetic monopole would be an object with a net "magnetic charge".

If these researchers had found magnetic monopoles, I imagine there'd be a lot more coverage, so it seems like it's much more likely to be a case of shoddy science reporting. If so, what is the actual concept they are attempting to refer to?

Comment: The article is horrible and makes no sense to me, and they don't even link to the PRL paper. I wonder if they're talking about the [magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole_moment).

Comment: Dont take such news stories too serious, popular science journalism is way too slopy up to misleading or even wrong these days...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article is pretty poorly written. As Siva said it doesn't even link to the original paper. So I just looked up the name mentioned in the article and found [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6310) which is probably what they're talking about (though this is just a guess). They measured the magnetic dipole moment of protons and antiprotons to ~4 parts per million (and verified the CPT theorem at this level).

---

And yes, magnetic monopoles still haven't been observed.